# C# Image.Save AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, image, memory-management, access-violation

I have a function, which builds image from pixel array and saves it to file. It works without problems when called once. But if I call it twice (after it's fully executed for the first time), the function throws `AccessViolationException`.

```
private void saveImage(byte[] bmpBytes)
{
    Debug.Print("Image saving started");

    var arrayHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(bmpBytes, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
    System.Drawing.Image bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(960, 540, 960 * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    bmp.Save("img.bmp");

    Debug.Print("Image saving completed");
}
```

So, `bmp.Save("img.bmp");` line throws the exception. I've also tried saving data in `MemoryStream`, but with the same result: success on the first call and `AccessViolationException` every other time. What the reason can be?

Comment: Is this your actual code? Which statement throws exactly? You're reserving pinned memory, then letting `arrayHandle` go out of scope without explicitly freeing it. Does the exception contain any message?

Comment: Yes, this is actual code and bmp.Save("img.bmp"); throws the exception with no message in it.

Comment: @keyboardP Added `using` but still got this exception.

Comment: @JustLogin - Sorry, removed that comment before you replied. If you don't overwrite "img.bmp" (e.g. random name), does the exception get thrown?

Comment: @keyboardP I get the exception even without attempting to write image to file. If I save in `MemoryStream`, the problem is the same.

Comment: @keyboardP Also, if I try to save image in files with random names, the I get one good file and another with only a half of picture (after exception throwing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error states that you are trying to access protected memory. Most likely you passed an array of a lesser size than your image required. It's similar to buffer overflow. So when GDI tries to read memory with your image, it goes beyond what's allocated for your process memory and a failure occurs. By the way, behavior is undefined. For example, if that piece of memory is already allocated to a process you will read whatever it has and receive no error. Most likely in this case you will see the image with some noise.

Are you sure you're passing an array of valid length? Try to add corresponding checks. And do not forget to free allocated memory - [GCHandle must be released with `Free` when it is no longer needed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Just ran that code and got no errors:

```
int width = 960;
int height = 540;

void Main()
{
    var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, width * height * 3).Select(i =>
    {
        i = i / 3;
        var y = i / width;
        var x = i - y * width;
        var xd = x / (double)(width - 1);
        var yd = y / (double)(height - 1);
        return (byte)((xd + yd) / 2d * 255);
    }).ToArray();
    saveImage2(arr);
}

private void saveImage2(byte[] bmpBytes)
{
    if (bmpBytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bmpBytes");

    if (bmpBytes.Length != width * height * 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid array length", "bmpBytes");

    var output = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var bmpData = output.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, output.PixelFormat);

    // Stride must be taken into account.
    // Actual row length may be greater then required due to GDI's internal memory alignment.
    // It is an error to copy entire array as-is, need to copy row-by-row.
    var rowBytes = width * Image.GetPixelFormatSize(output.PixelFormat) / 8;
    var ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(bmpBytes, i * rowBytes, ptr, rowBytes);
        ptr += bmpData.Stride;
    }

    output.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    output.Save(@"d:\temp\img.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This line of code `if (bmpBytes.Length != 960 * 540 * 3) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid array length", "bmpBytes");` saved me! In some cases I did wrong byte operations, so my array length was incorrect (it was like this for the second function call also, but OK for the first).

Comment: If I copy this code in new C# project in Visual Studio 2010 (I need Surface SDK 2, that's why I cannot use newer version), I get an exception: `Unhandled exception at 0x7576a96d in imageDecoder.exe: 0xC000041D`. It's in `bmp.Save` operation. But if I run program exe directly, it works fine. What's the trouble?

Comment: Is there any more details like inner exceptions, stack trace and so on? A numerous reasons could cause `unhandled exception`.

Comment: I'm very new to C# and Visual Studio, so maybe I do not understand right what kind of data do you need. But here is some from "Output" and "Call stack" windows: http://pastebin.com/bcWkXtvJ

Comment: Still not clear. I've updated answer, try `saveImage2` method.

Comment: Still got exception (and still no issues on runing exe directly): http://pastebin.com/2jVkgwWC

Comment: @JustLogin one more small yet important fix, but I guess this will not solve problem :( It's really hard to tell why this error happens. I don't have vs'10 to reproduce it and in vs'15 I don't get this error.

Comment: Now everything runs in VS without errors. Also I've tested all previous versions (including even one from my question) on another PC (with the same IDE). Not a single problem.

Comment: @JustLogin glad to hear that :). Just submitted final version with complete set of fixes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118030/discussion-between-justlogin-and-lorond).

Answer (score 0):

Upd:

```
System.Drawing.Image bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(960, 540, 960 * 540 * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
```

Comment: This doesn't help.

Comment: `960 * 540 * 3` this is a bad idea, because the parameter stands for how many bytes are used to describe one line of picture. So pictureWidth * bytesPerPixel is the right formula.

Comment: 960 * 540 - it's size of image. 3 - 3 bytes per pixel (24bpp - 24 bit per pixel).

Comment: @Arheus Yes, but this parameter is used not for the size of picture. MSDN: Integer that specifies the byte offset between the beginning of one scan line and the next. This is usually (but not necessarily) the number of bytes in the pixel format (for example, 2 for 16 bits per pixel) multiplied by the width of the bitmap. The value passed to this parameter must be a multiple of four.

Answer (score -2):

I also had such problem, but the only one way will be effective in that case.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
private void saveImage(byte[] bmpBytes)
{
    try {
     Debug.Print("Image saving started");
     var arrayHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(bmpBytes, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
     System.Drawing.Image bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(960, 540, 960 * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
     bmp.Save("img.bmp");
     Debug.Print("Image saving completed");
    } catch ( System.AccessViolationException ex ) {
         // Doing smth
    }
```

}

In common case, you can't catch AccessViolationException exception, so you need to add a [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] attribute

Comment: Please, read carefully https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#Four and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx (remarks section). Corrupted state is not valid and first of all you need to find a reason of this corruption and do not suppress it silently.

Comment: In this case there must be a good reason for corruption, so I don't think handling it without any actions is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks! I honestly tried to get an appropriate decision of the same issue. Now I understood, that I've to work more on that problem.

Comment: @JustLogin, as for me, this problem is covered in .NET libraries, especially in GDI+ interaction mechanisms.